# Showing that the class of finitely chromatic graphs is not closed under elementary equivalence without ultraproducts

Tags: logic, graph-theory, model-theory, coloring

The proof that I know of the class $C$ of finitely chromatic (possibly infinite) graphs not being closed under elementary equivalence involves ultraproducts as in the following.  First, one can show that if $C$ is closed under ultrapowers then it is also closed under ultraproducts.  Indeed, if $G_i \in C$ for $i \in I$, then the ultraproduct of $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ modulo $D$ can be embedded as a connected component of the ultrapower modulo $D$ of the disjoint union of $(G_i)_i$, which is finitely chromatic by assumption.    Then one proceeds by showing that $C$ is not an elementary class.  This is done by, for example, taking the ultraproducts of $(G_i)_{i < \omega}$, which is a sequence of finite graphs of arbitrarily large girths and arbitrarily large chromatic numbers $< \omega$.

Can one show the same thing without using 
ultraproducts?  That is, can I replace the argument with one that uses Loewenheim-Skolem, realizing/omitting types, etc.?

Addendum: bof has provided the proof of $C$ actually closed under $\equiv$, which I understand.  I'm confused; what's wrong in the argument above?

Comment: Compactness? :)

Comment: @RobArthan I mean "Not being closed under elementary equivalence."

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you me a little bit more specific?

Comment: $G$ is $n$-colorable if and only if every finite subgraph is $n$-colorable.

Comment: @RobArthan "$x$ is elementarily equivalent to $y$" is an equivalence relation (with class-sized domain and range).  A class $C$ is closed under an equivalence relation $R$ iff for all $x \in C$ and $x R y$ we have $y \in C$.

Comment: @RobArthan By "finitely chromatic", I mean "finitely chromatic"; that is, the graphs in $C$ has finite chromatic numbers.

Comment: If $G$ is finitely chromatic and $G\equiv H$ then $H$ is finitely chromatic. **Proof.** If $\chi(G)\lt\omega$ then $G$ is $n$-colorable for some $n\lt\omega.$ Therefore every finite subgraph of $G$ is $n$-colorable. Therefore every finite subgraph of $H$ is $n$-colorable. Therefore $H$ is $n$-colorable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not true. The error in your argument is that $C$ is not closed under infinite disjoint unions: if you have a family of graphs $G_i$ such that $\chi(G_i)$ is finite for each $i$ but not bounded, then the disjoint union will have infinite chromatic number.  So in fact $C$ may be closed under ultrapowers but not under ultraproducts, and this is in fact what happens (and correspondingly, it is closed under elementarily equivalence but is not an elementary class).

Comment: The point in the argument in the very first paragraph is that if $C$ is closed under $\equiv$, then it is elementary (i.e., $\mathrm{EC_\Delta}$).  I believe, however, that the argument right after that which uses an ultraproduct is what fails.  It shows that for each $n$ the property of $n$-colorability is not expressed by a single first-order sentence, but nothing more.  What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully before!